# Photoshop automate copying shapes and changing color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation

I am currently manually creating a set of cards. The cards consist of 1-5 copies of the same shape, in one of a handful of colors.

For example, I have a card with 1 red circle, a card with 2 red circles etc, a card with 1 blue circle, 2 blue circles, etc.. a card with 1 red squares, 2 red squares etc.

Essentially, a card has either squares, circles, triangles or octagons.

Instead of me creating a circle, then making versions in different colors, and finally versions with different numbers of them, is there any way to automate the copying and color changing of these items?

Comment: My only thought would be to use actions.

Comment: @AndrewH use scripts